# jQuery .load() not putting elements into the DOM

Tags: jquery, dom

have a series of files for each Spanish verb I am loading. The file names from a specific folder were put into a hidden list on the page using PHP. I am iterating through the list with .each() for the file name, then using .load to load the data from that file. I then use a function to filter the data for a specific class name and populate an unordered list.

The issue is that these li tags show up just fine on the page, but they are not being entered into the DOM and I can't click on them to activate that verb.

Here is how I am loading them with .load then later on trying to use .click:

```
$("#allVerbFiles p").each(function() {
    var newFile = (filePath + $(this).html() + " .vonly");
    $("#verbListHolder").load(newFile, function(){
        var verbName = $(this).find(".vonly").html();
        $("#verbList ul").append("<li class='verbName'>" + verbName + "</li>");
    });
});

$("#verbList ul").on("click", ".verbName", function(){
    verbMkr = ($(this).index() + 1);
    rolodex = ( 42 - (27 * verbMkr));
    $("#verbList ul").css("marginTop", rolodex + "px");
    nextVerb(); 
});
```

How can I make these li tags appear in the DOM for clicking?

EDITING MY OWN QUESTION WITH THE SOLUTION I FOUND - STILL WOULD APPRECIATE FEEDBACK

I am using the .delegate() method to make this work. I worked like a charm, but is this the best approach?

```
$(document).delegate("#verbList ul li", "click", function(){
    verbMkr = ($(this).index() + 1);
    rolodex = ( 42 - (27 * verbMkr));
    $("#verbList ul").css("marginTop", rolodex + "px");
    nextVerb(); 
});
```

Comment: If `each()` is iterating over multiple elements, isn't each call to `load()` going to replace whatever's currently there?  I imagine the callback function to `load()` isn't finding what it's looking for because something else has already overwritten it.  This looks like asynchronicity run amok.

Comment: Any error in console? What is the purpose of using `.load()` ajax method here in a loop? Is `#verbList` descendant of `#verbListHolder`? ETC... You'd have better to provide concrete sample in question itself and the relevant HTML markup

Comment: I used .load() in a loop to fetch the file name for each file name in the list. Is there a better approach?

Comment: To answer the first comment. I did fight the replacing issue, but this is why created the function with load and I fetched the html from that individual result and appended the verbList ul with a new li tag. The load element does change each time, but the append added it somewhere else.

Comment: Use `.on()` instead of `.delegate()`. The latter has been deprecated. Something like: `$(document).on("click", "#verbList ul li", function(){ ... }`

Answer (score 1):

If you see elements, they are in the DOM. It is your click-handler that was not attached correctly. The code you showed us repeated the `#verbList ul` twice, which is probably just wrong.

The way I think you would need to do this:

```
$("#verbList ul").on("click", ".verbName", function(){
  // ... the rest as is
});
```

or, if you have nested `#verbList ul#verbList ul` you should make sure html ids are really unique!